# How can I modify the look of a button located within a bootstrap modal using Javascript and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage that makes use of bootstrap modals to display information to the user, within one of these modals is a button that offers the user the ability to select certain functionality.

Within my webpage I have a function that makes a post request to an external API, this API returns a collection of data. Within this data there is a flag `externalProvider`, when this flag is set to 1 I want the text and link of my button to change. So that the button now has a different behaviour. If the `externalProvider` flag is not set, then the behaviour and look of the button remains the same.

The button is located within a bootstrap modal, the code for which is found below.

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="EditTask" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"> -snip- </div>
            <div class="modal-body"> -snip- </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success action-complete-task">The button who's text I want to change</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function openTask(taskId) {
    $.post(http://localhost:1000/endpoint/, function (data) {

        if (data !== "Failed") {
            if (data.externalProvider === 1) {
                //Change button design here
            } else {
                //Keep button design the same
            }

        } else {
            alert("An error occured");
        }
    });

    $('#EditTask').modal('toggle');
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the modal dialog will show before the ajax POST returns, right?

Comment: What do you whant to chang of the design?

Comment: @Forty3 Yes, the modal is first rendered and displayed, the POST request is made and then the modal is populated with data once the POST has returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding an id to your button to ensure that you are only targeting the button you want to update you can then use the below in place of your change comment to update the button text

```
$("#YOUR-ID").html('NEW TEXT');
```

for example

HTML

```
<button id="action-complete-task" type="button" class="btn btn-success action-complete-task">The button who's text I want to change</button>
```

JS

```
$("#action-complete-task").html('NEW TEXT');
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, still getting to grips with the markdown :)

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, you are using jQuery -

```
function openTask(taskId) {
    $.post(http://localhost:1000/endpoint/, function (data) {

        if (data !== "Failed") {
            if (data.externalProvider === 1) {
                //Change button design here
                $('div.modal-footer button', '#EditTask').text([...your desired text...]);
            } else {
                //Keep button design the same
            }

        } else {
            alert("An error occured");
        }
    });

    $('#EditTask').modal('toggle');
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to put an ID on the button and reference it that way? I simplified the HTML for Stack, in reality the modal contains a number of buttons.

Comment: Absolutely. @Jason's answer above is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the CSS styling that bootstrap applies by removing the classes "btn" and "btn-success" with JQuery's removeClass, then apply whatever css style you want using the addClass function:

```
$(".action-complete-task").removeClass("btn btn-success").addClass("newCSSStlying");
```

**Edit:**

By removing the classes it had before it wil look awfull so , it is better to add an class to overwritie the css.

I would somthing like: `$(".action-complete-task").addClass("newCSSStlying");`

Comment: I would not recoment removeing classes without a reason, just add the class with overwrites the older css, mutch less work.

Comment: That is fair. Just make sure any stylings that need to be adjusted are in the new style.